# How can I use a (three terms) decidable axiom in a case analysis?

Tags: coq

In Coq, I made some record structure $I$ and also make a strict order and equality $<$ and $==$.

And I showed that $a < b$ or $a == b$ or $b < a$ for every $a, b \in I$.

```
forall a b : I, a < b \/ a == b \/ b < a
```

Since my construction is not decidable, I use an decidable axiom.

```
Axiom I_dec : forall a b : I, {a < b} + {a == b} + {b < a}.
```

I want to use this axiom in case analysis. However, I cannot deal with all three cases.

For example,

```
Example example : 
forall a b : I, if (I_dec a b) then a < b else True. 
Proof.
intros. destruct (I_dec a b) as [[H|H]|H]. 
{ simpl. exact H. }
{ simpl.
```

I want to reach only the most left case $a < b$, however it is impossible for me.

Is there a way to deal with all three cases respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a problem with notations, incompatible with your use of `if`.
Let's have a look at `I_dec`'s  structure (I set `I = nat`).

```
Unset Printing Notations.
Check I_dec. 

I_dec
     : forall a b : nat, sumor (sumbool (lt a b) (eq a b)) (lt b a)
```

The main cases of `I_dec a b` are `(sumbool (lt a b) (eq a b))` and
`(lt b a)`.

A possible workaround (among others) is to define a variant of `if`:

```
Notation if' t t1 t2 :=
  match t with inleft (left H) => t1 | _ => t2 end.

Example example : 
forall a b : nat, if' (I_dec a b) (a < b) True.
Proof.
intros; destruct (I_dec a b) as [[H | _] | _]; auto.
Qed.
```